# RubyMine Heroku Remote Debugging with breakpoints

Tags: heroku, breakpoints, remote-debugging, rubymine

I am trying to remote debug with breakpoint a Ruby application using Heroku.
I have installed the Heroku Integration plugin and I am able to see the logs. But RubyMine does not stops at the breakpoints

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your config for remote debug?

Comment: It was a long time ago and I do not need that anymore more. Thanks for the interest anyway